# Code working in chrome but not in firefox in extjs

Tags: extjs

I m trying to set value to combobox in extjs, this is working in chrome but not in firefox. I used the following code:

```
 function callFromController(comboitemid,itemvalue) {
        Ext.ComponentQuery.query(comboitemid)[0].setValue(itemvalue);
 };
```

Comment: Which extjs version? Please provide jsfiddle reproducing the bug.

Comment: Whats the error you are getting?Did you debug it in firefox?

Answer (score 0):

AS a general guidence I would use:

```
function callFromController(comboitemid,itemvalue) {
    // make sure you add a # to your Id string or use Ext.getCmp insted.
    var foundComponents = comboitemid && Ext.ComponentQuery.query(comboitemid);
    if (foundComponents.length) {
        // I would add to see in your console.log('foundComponents[0]=%o',foundComponents[0])
        // to check the value of the found component
        foundComponents[0].setValue(itemvalue);
    }
};
```

Comment: hello Gabriel Kohen,                                                     I m sure about combo item id with #, and tried above code but not working in firefox. This code also working in Chrome.

Comment: Hi. Do you mind setting up an example in JSFiddle/Sencha Fiddle ?

Comment: I m trying to do like this                                           http://jsfiddle.net/Loyv03Lt/14/

Comment: @ShankarRade did I understand correctly on your last comment that the code is working both on Chrome and Firefox? Is so can we mark the question as answered?

Comment: Hello  Gabriel Kohen, I mean to say fiddle code is working fine in both Firefox and chrome but same code is not working in my application.

Comment: @ShankarRade, when trying the code snippet above in Firefox using your application, what do you see int he browser console or Firebug? Make sure you open the console before launching your app in Firefox.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel Kohen, solve this problem just increase ajax timeout

Comment: No worries @ShankarRade. Please make sure that your code can handle the asynchronous flow gracefully regardless of the AJAX timeout. Also, let me know if you want to mark the question as answered or close it.